# Hibernate reverse engineering for particular tables in a schema

Tags: hibernate, reverse-engineering, hibernate-mapping

I have installed Hibernate tool with eclipse for reverse engineering.

Now, I want to generate POJO and XML files for a new set of tables in a schema. When I rightclick and `Hibernate code generation configurations` it filters the schema and not the table. As a result the entire tables in the schema is reverse engineered. How do I reverse engineer particular set of tables?

Answer (score 0):

You probably thinking about this:

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create

> Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.
>   e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Eclipse, you can create a xxx.reveng.xml (file name can be changed as you wish) as below.

e.g.

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
<schema-selection match-schema="TRADE"/>
<table-filter match-name="PEOPLE"/> 
<table-filter match-name="PRODUCT"/> </hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Then you can set the above file name in the reveng.xml field in the Hibernate code generation configuration popup.

Then it will generate POJOs olny for two tables PEOPLE and PRODUCT under TRADE schema.